# Haskell. Return the index of the first repeated number

Tags: haskell

A list of integers is given. Determine whether the list contains the same numbers that follow one after another. Return the index of the first repeated number or -1 if there are no repetitions.

The function should output:

```
duplicateIndex [1,8,3,3,4] -> 2
duplicateIndex [7,7,3,2,5] -> 0
duplicateIndex [1,2] -> -1
```

I tried to solve as follows, but this solution is not correct!

```
let duplicateIndex lst =  [if x ==y then  lst !!x else (-1) |  x:ys <- tails lst, y <- ys]
```

Help me fix the code.

Comment: Something like `f ys = listToMaybe [ x | ((x,y):_:_) <- groupOn snd $ zip [0..] ys ]`

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? You should embrace the habit of reporting the error message. We can help you understand what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: use ol' regular recursion with an accumulator holding the last value an index. Then try to abstract recursion with a fold.

Comment: A common trick is to use `zip xs (tail xs)`

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension expression returns a list element rather than a list index (as specified). Furthermore, there is nothing to keep track of the current index value.

If we look for a solution that is easy to visualize, we can try using [zip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip). When it is about comparing 2 adjacent elements, it is common to use `zip xs (tail xs)` as an auxiliary list.

But that still does not include any information about indexes. For this, we have to add the index sequence as `[0..]`.

As ultimately we aim to return an index, an interesting list comprehension expression would start like:

```
[ ... | ((x,y), idx) <- zip (zip xs (tail xs)) [0..], ... constraints ... ]
```

Let's see what our auxiliary list looks like:

```
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines ys = mapM_  (putStrLn . show) ys
 λ> 
 λ> xs = [1,8,3,3,4,7,5,5,2]
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines $ zip  (zip xs (tail xs))  [0..]
((1,8),0)
((8,3),1)
((3,3),2)
((3,4),3)
((4,7),4)
((7,5),5)
((5,5),6)
((5,2),7)
 λ>
```

Furthermore, looking for a *repeated* number we need to have `x == y` as a constraint; and we want to return an index, so the left side of the list comprehension has to be `idx`. This gives:

```
[ idx | ((x,y), idx) <- zip (zip xs (tail xs)) [0..], x == y ]
```

Let's test it:

```
 λ> 
 λ> [ idx | ((x,y), idx) <- zip (zip xs (tail xs)) [0..], x == y ]
 [2,6]
 λ>
```

So we're almost done: we just need to take the first element of the last list comprehension, assuming of course there is a first element at all. Otherwise, return -1.

This gives the following code:

```
duplicateIndex :: Eq α => [α] -> Int
duplicateIndex xs =
    let  indexes = [ idx | ((x,y), idx) <- zip (zip xs (tail xs)) [0..], x == y ]
    in
         if (null indexes) then  (-1)
                           else  head indexes
```

The language lazyness ensures that the `indexes` list will not be evaluated beyond finding the first element.

### EDIT:

The function can be written in more compact fashion using [zip3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip3):

```
duplicateIndex :: Eq α => [α] -> Int
duplicateIndex xs =
    let   idxs = [ idx | (x, y, idx)  <-  zip3  xs  (tail xs)  [0..],  x == y ]
    in    if  (null idxs)  then  (-1)  else  (head idxs)
```

Comment: Thanks @jpmarinier for the detailed explanation! What a beautiful and elegant solution you wrote!